# Poster Frame Replaced by Live Stream when live

Tags: jwplayer

I am looking for a way to have jwplayer show a poster frame on load and then when a live stream becomes available switch to the live stream without refreshing the page.  We currently switch out a holding page with the player page in the time leading up to the live event.

I've seen others (apple live events being one) where when you launch the page containing the player a poster frame loads, then once the encoder is fired up the poster frame is replaced by the live stream.  I'd like to make this a clean experience for the user and not display any stream unavailable errors...

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Sid

Comment: Would it work having a looping video that shows whichever image you want? That looping video would be cleanly transitioned on the encoder side. This is a common way of creating landing pages with events short time before they start.

Comment: Yes in theory that should work - I'm looking for how to execute it in jwplayer. How can I have the player looking for the live stream to become available and switch?

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here:

- You set a looping video on your encoder, let's say, one hour before your live stream starts. Jwplayer is manually switched to that looping video by changing a URL server side. Once you are ready to go live, you transition your looping video to your live stream, which will happen smoothly on the player side as it would have been playing a video already.
- A more sophisticated approach it is having a websocket or long polling process in the player, open or polling for `liveState`. Once your encoder changes to live, a connection is made to the websocket or state is changed server side (on a URL the player is polling on).

Comment: I don't want to stream the looping video from the encoder....I'm looking for an elegant solution and was looking for code guidance to have the player check for the presence of the live stream and then switch to it. Any code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a playlist.

You can try the live stream first and if that fails rollover to the looping video. When loop ends, return to the beginning and test the live stream again. Sometimes its handy to have a pre-roll intro (sponsor) video.  This does mean that when a viewer stops watching the live, they get to see your loop video. Not usually an issue.

Playlists are also handy for BIG live event. Set up two (or more) encoders, generally using different backhaul paths, can also be different CDNs. They produce different streams. Then in your player use a playlist with "repeat" to cycle between the streams.

I've used this with different satellite bandwidth using two different satellites. Ingest was SYD and LAX. (I'm in NZ)

I also power the encoders off different supplies - via different UPS systems and even generators.

This way the system is fully redundant right up to the viewers device.

rich